# Sumatoria de porcentajes

Tags: c#

Buen día,

Agradezco su ayuda con este problema.

El resultado del problema debe ser el porcentaje de un rango de edad entre 12 y 30 años, también de que genero es quien sufre el accidente y si el vehículo esta matriculado en una ciudad.

Este es el código.

```
internal class Seguros
{
    private int usuario, anio;
    private double porcentaje = 0;   /* Declaración de las variables. */
    private int femenino = 1;
    private int masculino = 2;
    private int validar;
    
    public int getAnio()    /* Encapsulamiento mediante los métodos set y get para la variable anio */
    {
        return anio;
    }
    public void setAnio(int a)
    {
        anio = a;
    }
    public int getUsuario()   /* Encapsulamiento mediante los métodos set y get para la variable usuario */
    {
        return usuario;
    }
    public void setUsuario(int u)
    {
        usuario = u;
    }
    public int Transito()  /* Declaración de el metodo Transito. */
    {
        int[] anioNacimi = new int[usuario];  /* Utilizacion de los arreglos que guardaran la información suministrada por el usuario. */
        int[] sexo = new int[usuario];
        int[] registro = new int[usuario];
        for (int i = 0; i <= usuario - 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Favor ingrese año de nacimiento del conductor {0}", (i + 1));  /* Solicitud al usuario del año de nacimiento del conductor. */
            anioNacimi[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Favor ingrese el sexo del conductor: 1. Femenino  2. Masculino");  /* Solicitud al usuario del genero del conductor. */
            sexo[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Favor ingrese el lugar de registro del vehículo. 1. Bogotá,  2. Otras ciudades");  /* Solicitud al usuario, de la ciudad donde se encuentra matriculado el vehículo. */
            registro[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
        }
        for (int m = 0; m < anioNacimi.Length; m++)  /* Utilizacion de un ciclo, para validar rango de edad de los conductores. */
        {
            validar = anio - anioNacimi[m];
            if ((sexo[m] == masculino && validar >= 12) && validar <= 30)
            {
                porcentaje = 100 / anioNacimi.Length;
                Console.WriteLine("El porcentaje de conductores masculinos con edades entre 12 y 30 años. Es: {0} %", porcentaje );
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < anioNacimi.Length; j++) /* Utilizacion de un ciclo, para validar rango de edad de los conductores. */
        {
            validar = anio - anioNacimi[j];
            if (validar <= 30)
            {
                porcentaje = 100 / anioNacimi.Length;
                Console.WriteLine("El porcentaje de conductores menores de 30 años son: {0} %", porcentaje );
            }
            
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < sexo.Length; k++)  /* Utilizacion de un ciclo, para validar géneros de los conductores a registrar. */
        {
            if (sexo[k] == femenino)
            {
               
                porcentaje = 100 / sexo.Length;
                
                Console.WriteLine("El porcentaje de conductores Femenino : {0} %", porcentaje);
                
            }
            if (sexo[k] == masculino)
            {
                
                porcentaje = 100 / sexo.Length;
               
                Console.WriteLine("El porcentaje de conductores Masculinos: {0} %", porcentaje);
                
            }
        }
       
        for (int l = 0; l < registro.Length; l++) /* Utilizacion de un ciclo, para validar origen de los vehículos. */
        {
            if (registro[l] == 2)
            {
                porcentaje = 100 / registro.Length;
                Console.WriteLine("El porcentaje de vehículos, cuyos carros están registrados fuera de Bogotá. Son: {0} %", porcentaje);
            }
        }
       
        Console.ReadLine();
        return 0;
        
    }
}
```

Al ejecutar la consulta muestra resultados repetidos.

Ejemplo:
El porcentaje de conductores masculinos con edades entre 12 y 30 años. Es: 33 %
El porcentaje de conductores menores de 30 años son: 33 %
El porcentaje de conductores menores de 30 años son: 33 %
El porcentaje de conductores Masculinos: 33 %
El porcentaje de conductores Masculinos: 33 %
El porcentaje de conductores Femenino : 33 %
El porcentaje de vehículos, cuyos carros están registrados fuera de Bogotá. Son: 33 %
El porcentaje de vehículos, cuyos carros están registrados fuera de Bogotá. Son: 33 %

Quedo agradecido a sus respuestas.

Comment: Es que no debes calcular el porcentaje dentro del ciclo for. En su lugar deberías llevar un contador para llevar la cuenta de las personas que cumplen la condición. Luego cuando salga del for calculas el porcentaje dividiendo el contador entre el total de personas por 100.

Comment: Lo intento como me sugirió y sigue apareciendo la duplicidad en el resultado.    for (int l = 0; l < registro.Length; l++) /* Utilizacion de un ciclo, para validar origen de los vehículos. */
        {
            if (registro[l] == 2)
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine("El porcentaje de vehículos, cuyos carros están registrados fuera de Bogotá. Son: ");
                conta = conta + 1;

            }

        }
        porcentaje = (conta / registro.Length) * 100;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} %", porcentaje);

Comment: Por ejemplo, en el `for` de año de nacimiento dónde evalúas sexoMasculino. Cambia la línea •porcentaje....` por cuentaMasculino++; (cuentaMasculin la tienes que declarar). Luego en la línea siguiente al `for` calculas el porcentaje de masculinos: cout<< "porcentaje masculino: " << (cuentaMasculino / registro.length) * 100  << endl;

Comment: En el caso de vehículos quita la línea porcentaje, aún no puedes calcularlo porque no sabes cuántos vehículos son de tipo 2. Por eso es que cuentas cuántos registros cumplen la condición. Y luego del `for` recién calculas el porcentaje (fuera del for no dentro)  contá/registros.lengtj * 100.  Si lo haces dentro del for aparte que calculas mal el porcentaje (100/registros.length) lo haces igual a todos pero 100/registros.length lo único que haces es calcular que porcentaje es 100 del número total de registros. Por eso todos si. Iguales

Comment: Me sirvió mucho su explicación. Quedo inmensamente agradecido.